# Show records in a particular format

Tags: android

Friends I have a list view.I need to show in this particular way.[image]

```
14 May 2012 15:34   Arrival     X
16 May 2012 20:00   Departure   X
24 Aug 2012 20:00   Arrival     X
```

Please suggest me code changes for the same.Also find the code of xml attached here.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Title"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/detail"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Detail"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/data"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Data"
            android:textColor="#000000" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@drawable/error"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I have tried setting it on a particular textview but the alignment varies and the app is looking wierd when I check it from device to device.

Comment: Each is differen row. right??? (14 May 2012 15:34   Arrival     X)--row1   (16 May 2012 20:00   Departure   X)--row2

Comment: try the xml given below and reply back

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView1"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp" android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Title"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" android:textColor="#ffffffff" android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/detail"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Detail" android:textColor="#ffffffff" android:layout_weight="1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/data"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Data" android:textColor="#ffffffff" android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:background="@drawable/icon"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Any solution for better alignment ?It is working fine for large screen devices but for devices with small sizes it fails.. just like what I was trying :(

Comment: used this on smallest configuration available in simulator, it works fine.